# Creating stop-motion videos from images with PHP

Tags: php, image, video

Is it possible, using PHP, to create a video file (Format doesn't matter at the moment) from a series of images?

I'm not talking about making animated GIFs but real videos.

Comment: I've never heard of a PHP library that can do that.

Comment: The short answer will be 'yes'; however, there are so many discrete parts to such a task that you'd be best off tacking it in small chunks and asking questions accordingly. PHP may not even be the best tool. I.e. try reading a collection of images into memory and if you get stuck, let us know what you tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but why would you want to? PHP isn't suitable for writing video compression software (e.g. implementing an H.264 encoder yourself), much as a chainsaw isn't suitable for neuro-surgery. Use external tools like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to do it for you with far less hassle/pain.

Answer (score 2):

there is the ffmpeg-libary that can encode videos in php: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I only browsed the landing page, but it looks like the library is focused on accessing meta information and pulling still frames (decode). Can this library encode video as well?